# Magento : merging tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonym-process

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740555/how-to-get-model-and-product-collection-in-magento-2) while reviewing edits which had the `magento2` and `magento-2.0` tags (question is now edited).

It seems clear to me `magento2` should be merged into `magento-2.0`. The description reads :

> Magento 2.0, the next generation open source digital commerce platform

Worth noting, [it looks like magento is tagged per release](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) so that `magento2` appears redundant.

Or is the `magento2` tag supposed to be a placeholder for 2.x releases ?

What should I do ? I recently hit the *suggest tag synonyms* priviledge but not sure how to handle this (+ I need reputation in said tags, if I understand correctly, which I don't).